# Why is .NET Dictionary FindEntry faster than simple loop?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, msdn

I try to understand how .net C# Dictionary works. I always heard its search mechanism is fast.

While looking at the implementation i saw the following code.
The following is the FindEntry function as show in:
[MSDN implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,bcd13bb775d408f1)

```
private int FindEntry(TKey key) {
        if( key == null) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
        }

        if (buckets != null) {
            int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
            for (int i = buckets[hashCode % buckets.Length]; i >= 0; i = entries[i].next) {
                if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key)) return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Can someone please explain to me, why the above code is faster than a simple loop and simple check of the value?
Example:

```
private int FindEntry(TKey key) {
        if( key == null) {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
        }

            for (i >= 0; i = entries[i].next) {
                if (entries[i].key == key) return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table will help you to understand the concept of hash tables behind the dictionary

Comment: note that unless class `TKey` has not an overried for `operator==` you implementation will find the key only if `object.ReferenceEqual(entries[i].key, key)` is true, i.e. only if they are reference to the same instance.Very likely, this is not what you want

Comment: @GianPaolo C# compiler won't even allow you to use `==` operator except if the `TKey` is constrained to `class`, which is not the case with `Dictionary`.